# Why do these divs not have an hight when rendered?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I'm using React with Vite, TS, Tailwind and ShadcnUI

When mapping over the bars: Number[] in state I rendered out the right amount of divs, but they don't have any height to them. Is this a tailwind issue?

```
export const Diagram = () => {
    const [bars, setBars] = useState<number[]>(initArray(20, 100, 10))
    return (
         <>
       <Card>
        <CardContent>
             <div className="flex flex-row items-end justify-items-center p-8">
              {bars.map((bar, index) => (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className={`h-[${bar}px] w-auto bg-[#16a249] mx-2`}></div>
            ))}
             </div>
            </CardContent>
       </Card>
     </>
```

Tried messing around with absolute positioning and random css/tailwind settings. Nothing has worked so far

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using the `style` attribute to set the `height` CSS property:

```
<div
  key={index}
  className="w-auto bg-[#16a249] mx-2"
  style={{ height: `${bar}px` }}
></div>
```